# Grey lines appearing when pasting a selection - How to remove?

Tags: gimp, transparency, gradient

When I fuzzy select a section of an image, like so:

[image: Selecting the gradient out of the X Files poster]

Cutting it works fine:

[image: The same poster with the gradient cut out]

But when I paste it in I get these gaudy stripes of grey lines all throughout the image:

[image: The poster, but now there are grey lines along the cut path]

Zooming in, I couldn't see any discrepancies in the way it has selected parts of the image. According to Reddit, I should alter how the layer blends downwards, so I tried changing layer modes including the composite space, composite mode, and blend space. I have tried changing selection attributes such as Anti-aliasing, Select Transparent Layers, and Sample Merged.

All to no effect.

How can I paste this in without having said grey lines?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. It looks like you are trying to cut out the gradient from the image, but then you paste it back in. Why? You can see in your second image that the cut leaves some lines which are not selected. They will also be visible when you paste as they are missing from the selection. Cutting things like this is often a bad way of working. Something you do as a workaround when you don't have a layered document. I'm sure there is a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi, there was, the intent was to replace the gradient section, which I eventually achieved using a layer mask, however that still left gray lines which I then had to clean up. The cost of cleaning it up was lower as I didn't have to blend it into the gradient, but it was still extra work. If it truly is the case that selection is missing parts, then I am wondering how to ensure that it does not miss those parts. I tried altering a number of selection options to no avail. I'm not sure why the cut would have not selected those areas, as I zoomed into and could not see any breaks in the selection

Comment: I don't use gimp regularly, mostly Photoshop. But I guess the general principle is the same. In PS selected pixels below 50% opacity isn't shown with marching ants, so visually inspecting won't reveal them. "Fuzzy selection" of any kind on a flattened image has the problem that often the part you want to select have tones in common with the part you don't want to select. Manually cleaning up is almost impossible to avoid on some images. Would be easier if the image had very contrasting colors.